# UDP packet does not gets distributed in rr fashion in IPVS mode in K8S

Tags: kubernetes, load-balancing, kubernetes-ingress, aws-application-load-balancer, ipvs

I am running a kubernetes cluster with ipvs mode rr scheduler. I want to set the Udp time out of ipvsadm to zero, but the minimum value permissible for udptimeout is 1. (ipvsadm --set 900 180 1)

Can anyone help as I am unable to distribute Udp traffic in a round robin fashion from one server to another server due to 1 second of time out
I want to disable the udptimeout of ipvsadm